# how do i use a pipeline script file in Jenkins pipeline (Pipeline tab)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Beginner in Jenkins. I have set up Jenkins on Linux server and creating a pipeline. I see in a Pipeline Tab, where it asks pipeline script or pipeline script from SCM. i m not using any SCM. i have written the sample pipeline script

```
 pipeline {
  agent {
       node {
          label ''
            }
        }

  stages {
     stage ('check script')
         {
           steps
              {
                 script
                    {
                      println " Checking the bounce scripts of application"
                     }   
            }
     }
     stage ('Bounce Application')
        {
          steps
             {
               script
                 {
                    println " Bouncing the application"
                }
            }
        }
       }
}
```

i wanted to put the above pipeline script in a file on a Jenkins server and use/ call it here. Do we have feasibility of this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can directly embed this in the Pipeline code at the bottom of the GUI instead of checking it out from SCM if you want.

Comment: sorry Matt, let me rephrase my question. Is there any plugin/ any way where i can use my pipeline code which is in file (may be called PipelineFile) on jenkins server. I do not want to put my code (above pipeline code)  in Jenkins GUI or use any SCM.

Comment: the options are: SCM keeping your Jenkins file or in the Jenkins project configuration . However if you want to reuse code, you can use the Jenkins Shared Libraries . However still under SCM .